# Dumping Postgres schema from Google cloud SQL

Tags: permissions, postgresql-9.6, pg-dump, pgadmin-4, google-cloud-sql

Now this may look trivial but it is a managed service so I don't have the superuser rights. And various schema/tables/sequences have different roles/users as their owners so I can't just use pg_dump remotely as i expected as a lot of them will fail due to permission issues.

Their export function only allows "Cloud Storage export" which I would have to pay for again plus it dumps everything not just the schema.

Someone kindly let me know if I have missed something?

So I figure their superuser "cloudsqladmin" can do the entire dump but I am unable to login as that user and do the dump. Any advice?